# Is it necessary to use roofing felt paper between shed floor joists and subfloor

Tags: joists, subfloor, shed

I am building a 12x14 shed with pressure treated 2x6 on pressure treated 4x4 (resting on 4 inches of 57 stone). Before I put the pressure treated 3/4 plywood subfloor on should I also lay down felt paper over the joists to help increase longevity of the plywood (heard quality of pt plywood is hit or a miss these days).

Comment: Vapor barrier is basically what you are creating. If you don’t want to use felt put plastic on the ground, it has nothing to do with the quality of the plywood, constant moisture from the ground will shorten any wood product life span.

Comment: So is using the felt paper between the joists and the pressure treated plywood considered best practice? What issue is this solving? Thanks!

Comment: It helps extend wood products life OSB and plywood do degrade with moisture the felt is a vapor barrier so if you want to extend the life of the structure it is a good idea to use or a plastic vapor barrier on the ground, the + for felt is it is not torn up with critters as often if there are openings. I have never used pressure treated plywood. Usually when post and beam I use pressure treated posts. Or paint them myself (not as good).

Comment: Could you post a link to the correct type of felt paper (say Lowe’s or Home Depot) not sure if all felt paper is the same.

Comment: If you want best practice use tyvek it breathes better. 
If I were going to use felt or tarpaper in this case I would use 15 lb felt.I haven’t seen felt or tarpaper used for decades. As a vapor barrier normally plastic on the ground.